# Regular Expressions R

Tags: r, regex

I have scraped indeed.com and have the whole descriptions.

However, I want to scrape of any premium pay mentioned in the description

e.g. The spaces can vary throughout the examples

$ 1.00/hour 2nd Shift Premium

$ 1.00/hour 2nd Freezer Premium

$ 1.00/hour 2nd Refrigerator Premium

$ 1.00/hour 2nd cold Premium

$ 1.00/hour 2nd shi Premium

I have used the expression following code to extract

`str_extract(x,"\\$.+premium")`

Although it gives me the desired results but also extracts a lot of garbage

e.g. undesirable examples

1. $12.00/hour + $1.50/hour shift premium
2. $18-22/hr average rate eclipse advantage is an internationally recognized organization that provides outsourced distribution center services. we manage services on-site across north america with the focus of customer service and high productivity standards.why choose us? a great company begins with great people!we are a direct employer.weekly pay checks medical, dental, and vision insurances short term disability, life, and critical illness insurances vacation pay holiday premium

Can someone please help me out with this

Also if somebody could refer a good resource that will be great.

Thank you

Comment: Why are the two examples not desired? What is the rule? Do you want to match anything there, or not at all?

Comment: The examples are undesirable because it is not included in the business logic:

$ 1.00/hour 2nd Shift Premium

$ 1.00/hour 2nd Freezer Premium

$ 1.00/hour 2nd Refrigerator Premium

$ 1.00/hour 2nd cold Premium

$ 1.00/hour 2nd shi Premium

$ 1.00/hr Shift Premium

$ 1.00/hr Freezer Premium

$ 1.00/hr Refrigerator Premium

$ 1.00/hr cold Premium

$ 1.00/hr shi Premium

Only the mentioned are desirable

Also how do I start a string with literal $ sign, it does not work with ^

That is just a side note
@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Regex knows nothing about business logic. What are the regex requirements? `^` matches the start of string, if your match is not at the start of the string, do not use it.

Comment: starting with a $ sign and ending with premium.

Can have shift, freezer, refrigerator, cold and shi in between only

Comment: The requirements are rather strange, see what I got trying to meet them: https://regex101.com/r/nT9k6r/1

Comment: Yup they are, the requirements are strange because the the string might not have a fixed pattern.

e,g, $12/hr + $13/hour "antyhting in between" shift, freezer, refrigerator premium

I only need  $13/hour "antyhting in between" shift, freezer, refrigerator premium

Comment: But to match a string, you need a set of clear requirements, else, if there is no regularity, there is no regular pattern.

Comment: It is giving me an NA in my R studio. Looks good on the example through.

Anything that starts with $ sign and ends with premium and must have the following words in between       Shift, freezer, refrigerated, cold, shi

Comment: These requirements seem to include the first undesired string, `(?i)^\$.*\b(?:Shift|freezer|refrigerator|cold|shi)\b.*premium$`, see https://regex101.com/r/nT9k6r/2

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to trim '$' and 'Premium' from the string this should work:

```
x <- '$ 1.00/hour 2nd Shift Premium'
str_match(x,"\\$ (.*?) Premium")[2]
```

> [1] "1.00/hour 2nd Shift"

Comment: it works for this but fails when the input is x <- "Starting Pay: $12.00/hour + $1.50/hour shift Premium"

Comment: I had a space between the `$` and the `1.00` - remove the space in the str_match line:

`str_match(x,"\\$(.*?) Premium")[2]`